# '# flag in PostgreSQL when query for Vietnamese character in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

After I run this line on the Windows command prompt:

```
edudb_v2=# select * from student where student.first_name = 'Nhật Ánh';
```

It does nothing, and then when I hit enter second time it shows this:

```
edudb_v2'#
```

edit: before that I have also use this command:

```
edudb_v2=# set client_encoding = 'utf8';
```

to be able to read in unicode.

What does '# flag mean? How can I query for Vietnamese character in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0):

You have a mismatched quote somewhere.

You can type your query over several lines pressing enter each time. The prompt changes to show when you are inside a string literal or an unclosed bracketed expression.